# How to sign out from Azure AD automatically right after receiving a mail id from Microsoft Graph?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

In my ASP.NET web app I have added **Sign in with Azure** button. The project has already got its database to authenticate the user. So from **Sign in with Azure** button I am getting the email id using Microsoft Graph and then using that email id to create the token for specific user from the database.

The issue is that user can have multiple id registered in Azure AD but only single id is registered in Database. After signing in with id (that is not registered in database) Azure will authenticate the user but its email id won't work because that email id isn't registered in Database. The user will be re-directed to the homepage. But now when we again click on **Sign in with Azure** button then he's not being asked for different account details but signing in with old credentials again automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You can check this out https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/wsfederation?wa=wsignout1.0

This will sign-out all the users from Azure AD using the URL above.

Link to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/single-sign-out-saml-protocol) also check this [one](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/70628)